# On Form POST values are displayed in URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Controller's Action1 calls a view which contains the following HTML code:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action2","Controller",new {ID = ViewBag.Link},FormMethod.Post,new {@class =""}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" value= "Submit"/> 
}
```

When the user Submits this Form following method is called:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Action2(int ID)
{
   //Something
   return View("Display");
}
```

When this "Display" view is displayed the URL contains: //Controller/Action2?ID=1

How to avoid this values from being visible in the URL even after the FormMethod is POST?

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because you're sending the `ID` as a route value. If you want it to stay out of the URL, instead send it via a hidden input element

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action2"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="@ViewBag.Link" />
    <input type="submit" value= "Submit"/> 
}
```

Comment: What if I also want the "Action2" part of //Controller/Action2 to be out of the URL?

Comment: honestly, that would be a bit odd, but if you wanted to do that, the default route that ships with MVC will have the action name "Index". So if you were to rename your method to "Index" (and subsequent view) that would likely work.

Comment: I asked because in the MVC tutorials it was said that a FORM POST method is secure than the GET method. What ever is posted through POST would not be added to URL.

However, here the values were added to the URL. So lets say I want the URL to say Controller/Action1 but then the user posts a form with Action2 POST then the user's URL would again say Controller/Action2 while there would no GET method for Action2

Comment: 1. "secure" may be misleading, it just won't show in their browser history, but if you're not using HTTPS you're still vulnerable to Man in the Middle attacks. 2. I'm not really sure of a realistic scenario in which the action name would/should be sensitive/confidential information.

Comment: 1. Ok I understand that without SSL a site is still vulnerable but 2. If an action is only a valid for a post and the user refreshes the page that he will get 404 error right?

Comment: no, they won't get a 404, they'll modal dialog box from the browser asking if they want to re-submit. UNLESS, the POST runs then redirects them to a get (i.e. use a RedirectResult)